# SQL - How to split up specific query results between two tabs

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am really stumped by this. I am making a report and need to divide up my results to two separate tabs using static report filters depending on whether a specific string comes up in one of the columns or not. To be more specific, what I'm looking to do is make it so records only show on Tab 1 if both T1.CustomKey != 'X' and T1.CustomValue != 'Y'. The second condition is that if T2.Name or T2.Date = 'Many' to put that record on 2nd tab of the report. The final result should be

> Tab 1 w' no records containing both T1.CustomKey != 'X' and T1.CustomValue != 'Y' and no records with either T2.Name = 'MANY' or T2.Date = 'MANY'
>
> Tab 2 w' records that contain both 'X' and 'Y' as well as records that contain 'MANY'

My current code looks like this...

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID 
    AND T1.CustomKey = 'X' and T1.CustomValue = 'Y')  
AND T2.NAME != 'MANY' or T2.Date !='MANY'
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID 
    AND T1.CustomKey = 'X' AND T1.CustomValue = 'Y')      
AND T2.Name  = 'MANY' OR T2.Date  ='MANY'
```

Additional info:
'Y' is dependent on 'X', that is to say, if CustomKey does not equal X then CustomValue doesn't not matter.

I've been stuck for a while and fr some reason I'm getting results on my first tab with 'MANY' and I'm not sure why. I'm hoping it's just a small problem with the and/or logic and not something I would have to rewrite a ton of code for.

Comment: you do know and if process before or

Comment: I think you are simply missing some parenthesis. I think is what @Paparazzi was trying to say above.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'l try that for sure. Where exactly should they go? I'm guessing covering T2.Name and T2.Date?